# Restart the thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I need to restart the thread, which work is satisitfied to some condition. I have only idea to kill this thread and start a new. Maybe, someone have more smart method to do this, and which threaing tools I should use to solve this problem?

Comment: Once you kill a thread, you cannot restart it. Perhaps you need to suspend and resume the thread, of which there are several ways to do this.

Comment: You should look into Task and TaskCancellationSource, you can use these types to start and abort async tasks with .NET 4.0 or better.  does that sound like what you are trying to accomplish? MORE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there are multiple ways to do multithreading with c#.  Could you give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that represents how you're starting this thread, and where you want to "restart" it at?

Comment: Do you actually need to restart a *thread*, or do you simply have a unit of *logic* that is currently executing in a thread?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan problem is to create a programm: thread-master analyzes how threads-workers execute some unit(task), and if any thread do it wrong, thread-master should restart it. I'm only beginner in mutlithreading in C#, but I want to deal with it. Can I solve this problem by using Threading class?

Comment: First, avoid using `Thread`. It's expensive. Use the new `Task` class instead. And, in case of tasks, it's as simple as creating a new task object and add it to your list of currently running tasks (whatever said list may be).

Comment: @Shaamaan thank you very much, it's very good idea. How I can realize analyzation of thread-workes statuses in thread-master, when there execute the task? I try to use parameter of function, which workes were execute. So, thread-master analyzes this parameter.